# Which exception should be caught for nlohmann::json::to_cbor?

Tags: nlohmann-json

I'm using [`to_cbor`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/to_cbor/). I can't find any hint on what exceptions to catch in its documentation.
I compared it with the documentation for [`from_cbor`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/from_cbor/) where you can find some exceptions that can occur.

I guess when using `to_cbor` there still can be problems when for example the JSON is not valid.

- Should I just use `json::exception` because every other exception inherits from it?
- Or, maybe `json::parse_error`, because that is the only possible exception?
- Or, maybe I don't need any exception catching at all for `to_cbor`?

I never really had an exception happening for `to_cbor` but would want to be on the safe side.

Would appreciate some help on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an invalid JSON, it does throw a [`parse_error`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/parse_error/#parameters) exception so you might want to handle that.

See this example with **invalid JSON** [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vnWMTc8Tn) throwing `parse_error` exception. You might want to take a look at the implementation of `to_cbor` [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/6af826d0bdb55e4b69e3ad817576745335f243ca/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp#L23458-L23479).

Also, you might want to [create an issue](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/new/choose) on the repo for its inclusion in the docs (if there isn't one already).

---

Regarding

> I never really had an exception happening for to_cbor but would want to be on the safe side.

That might be because you never had an invalid JSON i.e. you most probably be validating it before the flow reaches `to_cbor`.